# R shiny module: call reactive data from parent server

Tags: r, module, shiny

I am trying to call R  shiny module with reactive data from outside the module, I read the tutorial and knew that '()' should not be included in the callModule argument for reactive data. However I got an error message: 
`Warning: Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 
     'list` after doing that.

Here is the code for the module:

```
pieTableUI <- function(id, header, titleInfo, width = 6) {

ns <- NS(id)

infoClick <- h3(header,
              tipify(
                el = icon("info-circle"), trigger = "hover click",
                title = titleInfo
              ))

tagList(
tabBox(
  tabPanel("Pie Chart",
           infoClick,
           htmlOutput(ns("piechart"))),
  tabPanel("Table",
           infoClick,
           htmlOutput(ns("table"))),
  width = width
    )
  )
}

pieTable   <- function(input, output, session, dataChart, x, y) {

 output$piechart <- renderGvis({
 gvisPieChart_HCSC(dataChart, x, y)
 })

output$table    <- renderGvis({
gvisTable(dataChart)
})

}
```

And I  called the module with:

```
callModule(pieTable, "agegroupplot", dataChart = agegroup_data, x = "AGE_GROUP_CLEAN", y = "n")
```

where `agegroup_data` is a reactive dataframe from the server.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're not adding parentheses after `dataChart` in the body of the `pieTable` function. To get the value of a reactive expression, it must be called, similar to a function.

```
pieTable   <- function(input, output, session, dataChart, x, y) {

  output$piechart <- renderGvis({
      gvisPieChart_HCSC(dataChart(), x, y) 
  })

  output$table    <- renderGvis({
     gvisTable(dataChart())
  })

}
```